# Add p-value of Hausman test (or other additional GOF measure) to texreg table

Tags: r, texreg

I use `texreg` to report the results of several random effects models (estimated using `plm`) in a table.

How can I add the p-value of a Hausman test (comparing each model to its fixed effects counterpart) to the goodness-of-fit measures reported by `texreg`? More generally, how can I report additional goodness-of-fit measures with `texreg`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a model object called `model`, you should follow three steps:

1) Execute `tr <- extract(model)` in order to create a `texreg` object.

2) Manipulate this texreg object. Example:

```
tr@gof <- c(tr@gof, 0.5)
tr@gof.names <- c(tr@gof.names, "new row")
tr@gof.decimal <- c(tr@gof.decimal, TRUE)
```

3) Execute your original `texreg` command, but include the `tr` object instead of the original `model`. Example: `screenreg(tr)`.

If you think a GOF measure should be included in an extract method included in the texreg package by default, you should make suggestions in the texreg forum on R-Forge.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to add p-value of Hausman test (and other additional GOF measures) to texreg table. This method will fetch the GOF measures automatically so you do not have to do it manually. Ask if you have any questions.

Suppose that "random1" and "fixed1" are your models

First make the Hausman test into an object

```
ph1 <- phtest(random1, fixed1)
```

Then extract the coefficients of your model

```
sf1 <- summary(fixed1)
names1 <- rownames(sf1$coef)
co1 <- sf1$coef[, 1]
se1 <- sf1$coef[, 2]
pval1 <- sf1$coef[, 4]
```

Then extract your choice of GOFs

```
pval.ftest1 <- (summary(fixed1)$fstatistic)$p.value
rs1 <- sf1$r.squared
adj1 <- sf1$adj.r.squared
n1 <- nobs(fixed1)
phtest1 <- fp.value.fixed1
```

Choose which GOFs to include in the table

```
gof1 <- c(pval.ftest1, rs1, adj1, n1, phtest1)
gof.names1 <- c("p\\ (F-test)","R$^2$", "Adj.\\ R$^2$", "Num.\\ Obs.", "p\\ (Hausman\\ test)")
```

Choose decimal places for GOFs

```
decimal.places <- c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
```

Create a texreg object

```
tr1 <- createTexreg(coef.names = names1, coef = co1, se = se1, pvalues = pval1, gof.names = gof.names1, gof = gof1, gof.decimal = decimal.places)
```

Check that everything looks OK with screenreg

```
screenreg(tr1)
```

Repeat the same thing for all of your models (fixed2, fixed3...& random2, random3...) if necessary.

Check that everything looks OK with all models before using texreg or htmlreg functions

```
screenreg(list(tr1, tr2, tr3, tr4, tr5))
```